# Jquery Autocomplete using XML - grab alternate result

Tags: jquery, xml

I have the following jquery Autocomplete form that pulls data in from a local XML file.

It works fine and displays the data as it should, but how can I return a specific data value into the search field?

For example, when searching for London, the auto complete returns values thus:

> London Heathrow Airport, UK -

Which is great - **BUT** I'd like it populate the actual search field by grabbing a specific XML ID, (The airport code = IATA) and add ONLY that to the search field - like this:

> > LHR

How can I achieve that ?

Here's the jquery code

```
@Nicola Peluchetti
```

Thanks for your help and answer - this is what I got from your comments - but it's not working - did I miss something ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArr = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "airports.xml", 
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml,
        complete: setupAC,
        failure: function(data) {
            alert("XML File could not be found");
            }
    });

function parseXml(xml)
{
//find every query value
    $(xml).find("state").each(function()
{
    //you are going to create an array of objects
    var thisItem = {};
    var thisItem[label] = $(this).attr("label") + ',  ' + $(this).attr("country");
    var thisItem[value] = $(this).attr("iata");
    myArr.push(thisItem);
});
} 



    function setupAC() {
        $("#city").autocomplete({
                source: myArr,
                minLength: 3,
                select: function(event, ui) {
            //replace the label with the value
            $(this).val(ui.value);
        }



        });
    }
});
```

and here's the airports.xml file snippet

```
<states>
<state label="London Heathrow" iata="LHR" country="UK" />
<state label="Syndey" iata="SYD" country="Australia" />
```

....

And the search form snippet

```
<label for="city">From</label></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (i modified the answer according to the comments) - You could modify this function:

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
    //find every query value
        $(xml).find("state").each(function()
    {
        //you are going to create an array of objects
        var thisItem = {};
        thisItem['label'] = $(this).attr("label") + ',  ' + $(this).attr("country");
        thisItem['value'] = $(this).attr("iata");
        myArr.push(thisItem);
    });
}
```

EDIT 2 - you don't need this second part: autocomplete automatically replace the "label" with the "value" if you specify both of them in the object

semplified fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/7cLxD/1/

Comment: Yes, I've played with that - but all i really want to return is "LHR" in the search field (but display the entire thing in the autocomplete dropdown) - thanks for the response though!  Any further ideas?

Comment: Sorry - didn't understand the question, i'll look it out! :)

Comment: updated the question to make it easier to read ;-) All input welcome.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly, but how to deliver that from an XML file - and ideally in the code I already have set up ?  Thanks heaps.

Comment: I edited my code above to show your modification (wouldn't let me add new code!)  Did I miss something ?

Comment: Yes ! Congratulations.  Thank you for this awesome help.  Kudos to you dude.  I like to ask another question - how to have two data sources, the first - the XML (default) and the second a fallback to url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON" - Can we chat ?

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't chat (i'm in the office and they don't like chat!), anyway try to post the question here and i'll look at it!)

Comment: No worries - I opened a new question here If you have time, I am raising a beer to you! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745447/jquery-autocomplete-combine-data-sources-primary-and-fallback

Comment: one more (simple I hope) question on this: If there are two form fields: e.g. #city and #city2 - where could I add the second - or is it easier to simply repeat the entire block?

Comment: For the last question i think that you could simply do: $('#city, #city2').autocomplete() ...look here http://jsfiddle.net/7cLxD/2/

Comment: Thanks. One last question - how could I apply a css style individual XML var thisItem data elements (country for example) that show in the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must change your `select` function:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    // here you are adding the full string:
    // `London Heathrow Airport, UK`, as .value
    $("#city").val(ui.item.value);
    // here you are adding the full string:
    // `LHR`, as .id
    $("#city").val(ui.item.id);

    $("#qf").submit();
}
```

But for this approach, you must change your way to create list.
More information with complete code you can see [Autocomplete demo with xml data](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#xml).